# Windows Task Scheduler to move files to a different folder

Tags: script, scheduled-tasks

I have my phone set up so that when it takes photos, it sends them to file on my desktop. I would like to have a task run once a day that checks the folder and then

1. Creates a folder on the external drive with the day embedded (e.g. Photos-2012-10-08)
2. Move all the files from desktop folder to the newly created folder

How do you go about creating a script that the Windows Task Scheduler can use to accomplish that goal?

Comment: Have you read up about batch file programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SET dd=%DATE:~0,2%
SET mm=%DATE:~3,2%
SET yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%

set curr_date=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%
set new_dir=S:\ExclusiveToBackup\Archived\%curr_date%

mkdir %new_dir%

move C:\Users\ZZZ\Dropbox\ToArchive* %new_dir%

pause